# Gaussian distribution using C++ no mean and standard devition

Tags: c++, random, normal-distribution

I have uniformly generated random numbers. Now I wan to generate random numbers using Gaussian (Normal) distribution. I do not know the mean and standard deviation. I have read this article: http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_TR1_random.html#normal, but it requires a mean and standard deviation! 
I am also aware that the Box-Muller transform is  is commonly used. This correctly produces values with a normal distribution. but again I do not know the mean and std deviation.
No boost please.
Can anyone help, please?

Comment: You're stuck if you don't know the mean and variance (standard deviation).

Comment: Asking how to generate a gaussian distribution without a mean and standard deviation is a bit like asking for a uniform distribution without a minimum and maximum value.

Comment: What do you know about the desired distribution? I assume you do have some sort of knowledge about how it should behave (otherwise what's keeping you from choosing mean and variance randomly?)...

Comment: I need to iterate the for loops in intervals of 4 degrees.  The interval [-45:+45] should be stepped over by 4 degrees [i have done this].  Then within an instance of this 4 degrees, I need to assume a Gaussian distributed trial in granularity of 2 degrees. So i do not know how to assume mean and standard distribution for this trail

Comment: @Grizzly what do you mean by choose mean and variance randomly? how is this done?

Comment: May be the question I want to ask is How can I convert a uniform distribution[-45 45]  into a normal distribution? how do i choose the mean and standard deviation?

Comment: The mean is the centrepoint of the distribution, the peak of the curve. The standard deviation effectively describes how 'spread out' the distribution is. You could use matlab or excel or some suitable free alternative to visualise some example distributions and pick a suitable value by eye, in the absense of any more principled criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate uniformly distributed (in a segment) random numbers, you need two parameters: the low boundary of the segment, and the upper boundary of the segment. Usually, they're 0 and 1 respectively, so you get numbers from `[0..1]` range.

Now, to generate normally distributed numbers, you also need two parameters: the mean and the standard deviation. They have a different meaning, however. The mean is a number around which your generated numbers will gather: if you specify, say, 15, you'll likely see 11, 17, 13, 21, 9, 12, 14, 11 etc., but not (usually) 290 or -562. And the standard deviation (sigma) basically determines how far the generated numbers may go away off the mean. Strictly speaking, a number of any magnitude may be generated: even if you specify the mean 0 and sigma `1e-6`, you still may get 1000 — but it's quite unlikely.

As a rule of thumb, almost all generated numbers will be in `[mean - 3 * sigma .. mean + 3 * sigma]` range, and I bet you won't see anything outside of the `[mean - 5 * sigma .. mean + 5 * sigma]` range in your life.

There is a notion of "standard" normal distribution: with mean = 0, sigma = 1. It means you will get numbers mostly in `[-3..3]` range.

I hope it helps somewhat!